# jQuery: Hide element when the script called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i create a file contains HTML and Javascript which loaded later via AJAX. One of the file will hiding element after loaded, but it doesn't work. Even if i find the element using document it can't be done by:

```
$(document).find("#hiddenelement").hide();
```

Or:

```
$("#hiddenelement").hide();
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).find("#hiddenelement").hide();
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).find("#hiddenelement").css("display","none");
```

HTML:

```
<table id="hiddenelement">
    <tr><td><input type='text' id="txInHidden" name="txInHidden" placeholder="Any Words"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not `.` after the `find`.

Comment: What u want exactly? Show your Html Code Also?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#hiddenelement").hide();
 });`

Comment: can you show html code please??

Comment: post your ajax code ? and Html

Comment: Please clarify - are *both* your html and js loaded via ajax? or just the html?  You need to add the hide code to the same code that makes the ajax call, *not* document ready.

Comment: @FedyVenom can you please post your ajax code ?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, both loaded via AJAX. The loaded JS isn't only contains hide script so i need to know how to hide it in one file.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh The AJAX works fine to load called file. Other JS called by this AJAX works well.

Comment: Your best bet is to refactor so all js is loaded up-front (not via AJAX), eg using namespaces.  If your ajax-loaded-js contains values specific to each ajax call then parameterise these out so that they can use attributes (eg `data-` from the loaded html).

Comment: js loaded via ajax is not automatically executed (this includes `$()`) - the code that makes the ajax must make a call to the newly loaded function via `.success` or `.done`

Comment: Yeah I agree with @freedomn-m there is an option for success fn, better use that to make it work

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah it worth, but i'm trying to put html elements and related JS in one file, so i don't end with searching when i trying to fix a problem or modifying. Thanks, i found the way with put the target element as children element.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal yeah it worth, but i'm trying to put html elements and related JS in one file, so i don't end with searching when i trying to fix a problem or modifying. Thanks, i found the way with put the target element as children element.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the JS script to hide element will only work when element exists on page. 
In your case which is after appending the content via ajax call and not on dom load. You need to call the script to hide the code after appending element.

Or, You can rather add CSS for element with that id:

```
#hiddenelement{
  display : none;
}
```

Comment: this also doesn't work, i already rechecked the element's id and in css even change it to another id. But after element loaded still it doesn't hide.

Comment: @FedyVenom: can you reproduce the issue in fiddle. use settimeout in fiddle instead of ajax call to append the content

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically hide from id. Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#hiddenelement").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the element is loaded dynamically document.ready function will not effect on the element. Call one of the jquery hide functions after the element gets loaded in your case it will be ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

Hide command success after i put the #hiddenelement as children element. So the HTML and JS look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divParent">
    <table id="hiddenelement">
        <tr><td><input type='text' id="txInHidden" name="txInHidden" placeholder="Any Words"></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).find("#divParent #hiddenelement").hide();
```

But i also can't explain why this is happens like this. Hope someone can explain it. I know that we can't directly modifying the element which created later so we need to find it from "document" but that cannot explain why this case only works for the children element. Thanks.